# Target 2 divs for one method?

Tags: javascript

I have the following function:

```
 $('#cover-drop-zone')[0].ondrop = function(e) {
```

How can I target two different divs with the above code? I want both divs to have the ondrop method.

Comment: If you don't mind me asking, why the index?

Comment: It's to target the element. It's the same as document.getElementById. Jquery uses a wrapper so can't use just $('#cover-drop-zone')

Comment: Learn something new everyday, cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not use jQuery:

```
$('#cover-drop-zone, #other-element-id').on('drop', function(e){
    // do stuff here
});
```

Because your question isn't tagged with [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery), you could instead use plain JavaScript:

```
var elems = document.querySelectorAll('#cover-drop-zone, #other-element-id');

function dropFunction (e) {
     // e is the event (passed automatically as the first parameter,
     // this will refer to the element on which the function is called
    // and whatever your function would/should do...
}

for (var i = 0, len = elems.length; i < len; i++){
    elems[i].addEventListener('drop', dropFunction);
}
```

References:

- [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

Answer (score 0):

With this code :

```
$('#cover-drop-zone, #div2').bind('ondrop ', function(e) {  })
```

Comment: Don't use `.bind`. Use `.on`. You can read more about that in http://api.jquery.com/bind/

Comment: @nbar: Thanks for the clarification, I didn't know that there was a difference between on and bind.